# What does the $posts_join filter join to?

Tags: sql, join-tables

I am trying to use the `posts_join` filter to join 2 tables: `wp_postmeta` to `wp_posts`.  I am a novice at SQL, so I'm not sure if I am confused because I don't understand how WordPress is implementing `posts_join`, or if I just don't understand the SQL syntax.

My questions are:

1. Why is only one table used in the join statement? I thought 2 tables
   were needed for a join statement
2. Is this because the `posts_join` filter assumes you are always joining a table to `wp_posts`?

The example in the Codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join
uses a similar situation of joining `wp_postmeta` to `wp_posts`.

`$join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";`

Based on this example, I can see that `$wpdb->postmeta` (i.e. `wp_postmeta`) is explicitly stated as one of the tables to join.  But from my understanding of SQL, I thought `$wpdb->posts` would also have to be stated BEFORE the ON clause, like so:

`$join .= "$wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";`

So I am very confused why `$wpdb->posts` is not specified before the ON clause.  How else does WordPress know what is the second table to be joined?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts_join` is only a part of the full SQL query, the table you're joining to is referenced earlier in the query.

You can see the full query with the [`posts_request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_request) filter.

See the documentation for the rest of the [query filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/#WP_Query_Filters).

Answer (score 0):

The posts_join filter is referencing joins to the 'posts' table, i.e. wp_posts

That's why it's called the 'posts_join' filter.

You need to use this filter if you wish to be able to select columns from additional tables in your output or if you want to be able to filter by columns from other tables in your WHERE clause - although if you are joining in order to filter, you could just use a WHERE EXISTS or WHERE NOT EXISTS instead.